# Swift Data to base64 String with data:content/type

Tags: swift

I am trying to send an image to the backend and it needs to be a Base64 encoded String but adding:

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

at the beginning of the Base64String. So my string would look like that:

```
let imageBase64WithHeader = """
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAERlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA6ABAAMA

...

Ym48kN77Vtm7vkU0HDjfH3t6air16KLX+DWftQfvld2NP/z9TrRKvugPGKwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
"""
```

For my testing I am using the [Following web](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image) and chose DataUri as the output format

Is there any Swift method for that?

so far:

```
myImageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Just returns, as expected the base64 String but with no header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alobaili made a good point. In the end, I ended up implementing a Data extension like that rather than hard coding it has we support different formats.:

```
extension Data {
    /// Returns the image format if known
    var imageFormat: ImageFormat {
        guard let header = map({ $0 as UInt8 })[safe: 0] else {
            return .unknown
        }

        return ImageFormat(byte: header)
    }
    
    /// Returns the base64 String representation of an Image data:image/png;base64, **BASE64STRING**
    var imageBase64URIOutputString: String? {
        guard let mimeType = imageFormat.mimeType else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return "data:\(mimeType);base64,\(base64EncodedString())"
    }
}
```

Where:

```
enum ImageFormat: String, CaseIterable {
    /// Is a PNG image
    case png
    /// Is a JPEG image
    case jpeg
    /// Is a GIF image
    case gif
    /// Unknown image format
    case unknown
    
    /// Initialises the image format
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - byte: The byte that identifies the format
    init(byte: UInt8) {
        switch byte {
        case 0x89:
            self = .png
        case 0xFF:
            self = .jpeg
        case 0x47:
            self = .gif
        default:
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
    
    /// Returns the mimeType for the image. If image format is png, **image/png** will be returned. If image format is unknown, **nil** will be returned
    var mimeType: String? {
        switch self {
        case .unknown:
            return nil
        default:
            return "image/" + rawValue // Avoid using \()
        }
    }
}
```

And can be call like that:

```
print(myImageData.imageBase64URIOutput)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate the desired header to the string like that:

```swift
let header = "data:image/png;base64,"
let imageBase64WithHeader = header + myImageData.base64EncodedString()
```